# text field autocomplete (in field) as you type

Tags: jquery, ajax, text, autocomplete, box

I'm trying to develop a feature that makes suggestions based on what's in the database already or allows you to put your own value. It's a way of letting the user know what's already in the system in case they want to categorize something similarly. So I've done that.

The catch is that the code below provides a drop down and I can't figure out what words to search in google to get a tutorial for the kind of inline completion where you type and it fills in the rest of the word as you type right in the box itself, no drop down.

Anyone got any suggestions?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Auto Complete Input box</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.autocomplete.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
    <script>
$(document).ready
(function()
{
    $("#tag").keyup
    (function() 
        {
            var tag= $(this).val();
            if(tag!='')
            {
                $.ajax(
                {
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "autocomplete.php",
                    data: "q=" + tag,  
                    cache: true,
                    success: function(result)
                    {
                        $("#tag").val(result);
                    }
                }
                );
            }
            return false; 
        }
    );
}
);
</script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form method="post" action="input.php">
    Please put something in: <input name="tag" type="text" id="tag" size="20">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

    <?php
    $mysqli=mysqli_connect('localhost','XXXXXXXXXX','XXXXXXXX','XXXXXXXXXXX') or die("Database Error");
     $sql="SELECT auto_complete_suggestions FROM auto_complete";
     $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql) or die(mysqli_error());
    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

which is linked up to this piece

```
    <?php
     $q=$_GET['q'];
     $my_data=mysql_real_escape_string($q);
     $mysqli=mysqli_connect('localhost','XXXXXXXXX','XXXXXXXXXX','XXXXXXXXXX') or die("Database Error");
     $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT auto_complete_suggestions FROM auto_complete WHERE auto_complete_suggestions LIKE '%$my_data%' 
 ORDER BY CASE WHEN auto_complete_suggestions = '$mydata' THEN 0  
               WHEN auto_complete_suggestions LIKE '$mydata%' THEN 1  
               WHEN auto_complete_suggestions LIKE '%$mydata%' THEN 2  
               WHEN auto_complete_suggestions LIKE '%$mydata' THEN 3  
               ELSE 4
          END, auto_complete_suggestions LIMIT 0,1";
     $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql) or die(mysqli_error());

     if($result)
     {
      while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {
       echo $row['auto_complete_suggestions']."\n";
      }
     }
    ?>
```

I was assuming this would be an AJAX or JQuery task but I'm not finding any examples so any help pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

To be concise: looking to build a feature that completes text as I type and provides the suggestion directly in the text box.

Thank you!

Comment: follow this link : http://www.9lessons.info/2009/06/autosuggestion-with-jquery-ajax-and-php.html for a basic system

Comment: unfortunately that's exactly what my script above does. I'm looking for it to put the result directly into the text box

Comment: made updates to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you would want to have the suggestion from the database placed in the "tag" textbox. If this is the case you could do something allong the lines of this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#tag").keyup(function() 
{
    var tag= $(this).val();
    if(tag!='')
    {
        $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "autocomplete.php",
        data: "q=" + tag,  
        cache: false,
        success: function(result)
        {
            $("#tag").val(result);
        }
        });
    }return false; 
});
});
```

Although you would then have to limit your result to one record.

In your autocomplete.php (I assume thats the second code snippet) you would do:

```
$sql="SELECT DISTINCT auto_complete_suggestions FROM auto_complete WHERE auto_complete_suggestions LIKE '%$my_data%' ORDER BY auto_complete_suggestions LIMIT 0,1";
```

This would make an AJAX call once the keyup event triggers and search using the value of your tag textbox.

Comment: I tried that out but it almost seems like it's getting stuck in a forever loop somehow where the user types the letter 't' and then 'tiger' comes up and you're left with the whole word in the box now and when you try to type or delete it's still just bringing up 'tiger' because that's what was in the box.

Thoughts?

Comment: Does it actually make a new ajax call if you type in something different? (You can check this under the Network tab when you right click inspect element)

Comment: yup I typed "help" and it just kept replacing the letters with "add" and shows 4 separate GET

autocomplete.php?q=h
autocomplete.php?q=adde
autocomplete.php?q=addl
autocomplete.php?q=addp

so really I'm hoping it will boil down more like when i type "h" it suggests "help" but then when i type the entire "help" and add an "e" it will suggest "helper"

Comment: I assume you first typed in "add" and then tried to type in "help"? You could always add checks to the function, e.g. making sure the result is only placed in the textbox when the current string in the textbox matches the start of the result.

Comment: nope, didn't type add, it suggested that right off the bat no matter what letter i typed and then wouldn't let me delete it.

Comment: Is your query also showing the results you expect it to? You can view the results of your query by navigating to autocomplete.php?q=keyword and typing your keyword in the url.

Comment: Ah, so there in lies the issue. When I enter auto_suggest/autocomplete.php?q=f the word "add" shows up and for any other query as well so for some reason it's only prompting that choice rather than the best match.

Comment: I suggest changing your  query to "SELECT DISTINCT auto_complete_suggestions FROM auto_complete WHERE auto_complete_suggestions LIKE '$my_data%' ORDER BY auto_complete_suggestions LIMIT 0,1", that way you only find results that start with the requested data

Comment: It actually ended up being that  $my_data=mysql_real_escape_string($q) was actually returning completely empty for some reason. I don't know why. I've got some more questions but I'm going to start them new because they're in a different direction.

Comment: That might be because there is no connection available, try placing  that code after you connect to the database.